# Music not playing on Button Click

Tags: java, android, button, audio

Can't find out what sort of problem lies in it. Please help rectify. If one presses the first button, music will start and if he clicks the second button before the first piece of music ends, the second music will start after stopping the first piece.

```
package com.example.buttonsonic;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

    }
    public void button1 (View v){
        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mp.release();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.muzika);
        mp.start();
    }

    public void button2 (View v){
        Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        mp.release();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.muzikb);
        mp.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
       mp.release();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please re frame your question?

Comment: Sure. Actually I tried to create a program in which there will be two buttons and if I press the first button, a piece of music should play and if I press the second button, the second piece of music would start playing but the first piece of music would stop and vice versa. But I clicked the buttons but no music played. I wonder where the problem lies. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Modified your source code a bit. Now its working for me.

Activity Source:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
}

public void button1(View v) {
    // Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mp.release();
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.muzika);
    mp.start();
}

public void button2(View v) {
    // Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    mp.release();
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.muzikb);
    mp.start();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mp.release();
}

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="button1"
    android:text="Music 1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="button2"
    android:text="Music 2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help. I shall try on my computer and let you know. Thanks a lot again for sparing your precious time.

Comment: In short, I've to pronounce that you're brilliant. Being a novice, I tried my best but failed; your simple approach made it successful! I am truly grateful to you. It ran several times successfully and it shows hows impeccable your codes are. But after running several times flawlessly, the project started crashing, probably due to some error pertaining to the emulator. Console displayed: Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE. Added android:installLocation="preferExternal" to the Manifest but nothing changed at all. What should I do now?

Comment: That means there is less memory in emulator memory. So try deleting other applications. It will work then

Comment: I wonder there is some instability in android programming because sometimes without any cause, errors emerge and all on a sudden, the same application run smoothly. Wholehearted Thanks to you and I shall revert to you if I need any sort of advices or suggestions. THANKS A LOT.

Comment: public void imageButton1(View v) {
 if(mp.isPlaying()){
  mp.release();
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Music Stopped!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }else{
 mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.boysofsummerdjsammy);
    mp.start();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "First Score!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}   PLEASE SEE THROUGH THE CODES. I ADDED THE CODE FOR ONE BUTTON OUT OF THE WAY FOUR ONES. YOU WILL EASILY UNDERSTAND. PROBLEM IS THAT I PRESSED A BUTTON TO START AND ANY BUTTON TO STOP MUSIC BUT THE PROGRAM CRASHES AS SOON AS I PRESS ANY BUTTON TO START A MUSIC AGAIN.

Comment: I hope I could explain my problem. I replaced four buttons (you taught me) with image buttons. The program performs perfectly till second press but as soon as I click a button to start a music, message displays: "Unfortunately the program has stopped." Due to lack of space, I just included the code for a single button, instead of whole four buttons. The whole program remains the same as you prescribed but made a little change of inside button codes. Hopefully you can understand my words. Yes I have marked your answer as accepted.

Comment: I have replied to your query in the question you have asked in this site.